# Bootstrap, Less and Visual Studio (Chirpy) causing IE Filter Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, less, chirpy

I am using Chirpy to generate LESS files for me, but the filter gradient used in IE keeps rendiner the following output which is causing blue-black gradient.   If I remove the alpha and () it works fine, but no gradient.  Is there something wrong with the compiler?

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='argb(#0088cc)',endColorstr='argb(#0077b3)',GradientTy
```

The header and footer should have a red gradient background.

[image: The header and footer should have a black gradient background.]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using an old version of dotless (a .NET LESS compiler) which didn't support the argb function.

The intended result is that `argb(#222)` is translated to `#ff222222`

The latest dotless fixes this for me - perhaps there is a newer version of chirpy?

If not, you could try removing the argb calls from the filter rules in bootstrap's mixins.less file.

A correct filter value is something like this:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff222222', endColorstr='#ff111111', GradientType=0)
```